# How to display a certain number of rows in a DataGrid? (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

How to display a certain number of rows in a DataGrid? For example, only the first 15?

DataTable has dynamic data. I need to display the first 15 lines. And the rest should also be present, but not displayed.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CsvGrid" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding csvTable}">


DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
...
CsvGrid.ItemsSource = csvTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: You should check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661998/simple-way-to-display-row-numbers-on-wpf-datagrid
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042832/how-to-display-a-large-number-of-rows-in-a-datagrid

Comment: @EasyHax This is not exactly what I need ...

Comment: `CsvGrid.ItemsSource = csvTable.DefaultView.Cast<DataRowView>().Take(10);`

Comment: @EdPlunkett But since I do not receive all the data, I need to hide them.

Comment: @MiT I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means. What do you need to hide?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I need to display the first 15 lines. And the rest should also be present, but not displayed.

Comment: @MiT Put them all in a list. Make the list a private field of your class called `_csvRowList` or something. When you want to show all of them, use the whole list. When want the top 15, assign `_csvRowList.Take(15)` to ItemsSource. You'd be better off doing it with a Binding, but one thing at a time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can not, I have in the DataTable dynamic data.

Comment: @MiT Why don't you add that important requirement to your question? Also, please add any other important requirements you haven't mentioned, if 
any.

Comment: @EdPlunkett done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CsvGrid" ColumnWidth="*" LoadingRow="CsvGrid_LoadingRow" ItemsSource="{Binding csvTable}" />

private void CsvGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()+1).ToString();
    if(e.Row.GetIndex() > _showRows - 1) e.Row.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```